# How to disable stacking mode (turn on standalone mode) on Dell PowerConnect 6248?

Tags: dell, dell-powerconnect

I know there's button on Dell 35xx that I can change the stacking status during the reboot. But on Dell 6248 I didn't find such function, nor did I find the way to disable in the manual.

In Dell 6248's manual, it did mention when all Stacking LEDs are off, "The unit is operating as a standalone switch." So there must be a way to set it, but so far I didn't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well these are stackable switches by design, so you can't opt-out form this.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, maybe I didn't state my question clear. I actually want to configure it in "standalone" mode. In Dell 6248's manual, it did mention when all Stacking LEDs are off, "The unit is operating as a standalone switch." So there must be a way to set it, but so far I didn't find it....

Comment: But would that mean to delete the config file during the startup?

Comment: And re-upload the version again but without stacking enabled.

Comment: Somewhat reconfiguring stack node to the standalone would require this definitely.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not have another switch connected to the stacking port it will function as a standalone switch.